# Remove rows if string matches X but not Y

Tags: r, string, filter, subset

I have the following data frame:

```
data <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                   exposure = c("BMI", "BMI etc.", "BMI neuronal", "WHRadjBMI", "WHR", "BF"))
```

```
    
    id  exposure
1   1   BMI
2   2   BMI etc.
3   3   BMI neuronal
4   4   WHRadjBMI
5   5   WHR
6   6   BF
```

I want to remove all rows from this data frame which have "BMI" but not "adj" in the `exposure` column so that I can group all of the BMI related rows into a single factor level called "BMI. The real data frame is ~2500 rows by 50 columns.

Subsetting would therefore result in the following data frame, here rows 1, 2, and 3 have been removed because they contain "BMI" but do not contain "adj":

```
    id  exposure
4   4   WHRadjBMI
5   5   WHR
6   6   BF
```

I can then combine the "BMI" but not "adj" containing rows into a single factor level such that rows 1, 2, and 3 would become:

```
    id  exposure
1   1   BMI
2   2   BMI
3   3   BMI
```

I can do this final part as follows:

```
data$exposure <- "BMI"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `grepl` to remove the rows and converge all BMI exposure values to a single `BMI` value.

```r
data <- data[!grepl("BMI", data$exposure, fixed=TRUE) ||
             grepl("adj", data$exposure, fixed=TRUE), ]
data$exposure <- ifelse(grepl("BMI", data$exposure, fixed=TRUE),
                        "BMI", data$exposure)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you want

```
within(
  data,
  exposure <- gsub("^(?<=BMI).*", "", exposure, perl = TRUE)
)
```

which gives

```
  id  exposure
1  1       BMI
2  2       BMI
3  3       BMI
4  4 WHRadjBMI
5  5       WHR
6  6        BF
```

Comment: This works exactly as I wanted (though im not quite sure how?). I think its just changing every instance of "BMI" followed by any string of characters to just "BMI". As such it won't change anything where "BMI" comes after a string?

Comment: @matt Yes, that's right. The substitution happens as if the pattern is matched.

Comment: Note that this would also replace the value `WHRBMIadj` with `WHRBMI`, which according to the OP's rules shouldn't happen.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the reminder. I missed `^` but now fix it. hope it resolves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using base R + stringr:

```
library(stringr)
data[str_detect(data$exposure, 'BMI') & str_detect(data$exposure, 'adj', negate=TRUE),]
```

You have two logical conditions combined with a logical AND: `data$exposure` contains `BMI`, and `data$exposure` does not contain `adj`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
library(tidyverse)

filtered_data <- data %>%
  filter(!stringr::str_detect(exposure, "^BMI")) %>%
  mutate(exposure = "BMI")

filtered_data
  id exposure
1  4      BMI
2  5      BMI
3  6      BMI
```